# Secure C++ coding practices

Tags: c++, security, secure-coding

I am looking for a comprehensive record of secure coding practices in C++.
Since i haven't found such a list existing here already we might as well make this into a community wiki, for further reference.
I am looking for solutions to security issues like stack and heap based buffer overflows and underflows, integer overflows and underflows, format string attacks, null pointer dereferencing, heap/memory inspection attacks, etc..

NB: Besides coding practices, secure libraries that defend against these kind of attacks are worth mentioning too.

LE: As suggested by MSalters in comments this question has been split into two separate questions one for C++ and one for C.
Also see [Secure C coding practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780873/secure-c-coding-practices).

Comment: If you're intending to make such a list, I recommend making two. C and C++ need entirely different lists. You can't recommend "Use `std::string` instead of `char*`" to C programmers.

Comment: Maybe books from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: @MSalters that's a good point, though it's kind of hard to do that now that we have replies and comments rolling. Any ideas how can i split them the right way, without losing the current activity?

Comment: Split done. This one has been converted to a C++ one since most of the C only answers already here can be applied to C++ too, but not otherwise. C only question can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780873/secure-c-coding-practices.

Comment: Consider adding a C++-faq tag.

Comment: @Will: Please do not use the `c++-faq` tag lightly. We strive to keep a small body of really frequently asked question in there, rather than adding anything that seems interesting.

Comment: While a good question, it might be a better fit for programmers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The book [Writing Secure Code](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780735617223/samplepages/9780735617223.pdf) (only sample pages in this link) is very good at explaining security issues and how to avoid them. The book has been out for a while, but most of the topics covered are still relevant.

Answer (score 4):

Herb Sutter "Exceptional C++" and "C++ Coding Standards". Invaluable.

Marshall Cline [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/). Will tell you everything about common pitfalls. Free online.

Answer (score 1):

I found this book very useful [Secure Programming Cookbook for C and C++: Recipes for Cryptography, Authentication, Input Validation & More](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596003943)

It has a lot of examples for both Linux (posix)  and Windows unlike the previous mentioned [Writing Secure Code, Second Edition](https://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780735617223/samplepages/9780735617223.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

The
[Joint Strike Fighter Air Vehicle C++ Coding Standards](http://www.jsf.mil/downloads/documents/JSF_AV_C++_Coding_Standards_Rev_C.doc)
is a good start, even though it does apply mostly to reliability rather than security.

Answer (score 1):

The [SEI CERT C++ Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=88046682) is especially developed to cover all kind of security issues. CERT stands for Computer Emergency Response Team, which is an expert group that handles computer security incidents.

Answer (score 0):

Let me kick it off

- Avoid dynamically allocated
  memory using malloc
- (related) use fixed size
  array when ever possible, or infact in C++ avoid C style arrays when practical
- avoid the use of `(void *)`