# Secure C coding practices

Tags: c, security, secure-coding

I am looking for a comprehensive record of secure coding practices in C. Since i haven't found such a list existing here already we might as well make this into a community wiki, for further reference. I am looking for solutions to security issues like stack and heap based buffer overflows and underflows, integer overflows and underflows, format string attacks, null pointer dereferencing, heap/memory inspection attacks, etc..

NB: Besides coding practices, secure libraries that defend against these kind of attacks are worth mentioning too.

LE: As seen in this question [Secure C++ coding practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780410/secure-c-coding-practices) but for C only.

Comment: Since you are looking for secure coding practices, does this imply that the planned system does not yet exist? If so, perhaps it would be worthwhile to investigate a larger solution space, and include also programming languages other than C. Reading your list of  vulnerabilities, there are industrial-strength programming languages which by design prevent stack and heap based under/overflows, integer under/overflows, format string attacks, pointer related issues (google for SPARK, for example).

Comment: The basic solution to security is to code with strict contracts, and then throw in a few extra layers of safety in case you accidentally break one of your contracts. :-)

Comment: Title is an oxymoron. Like Schedler said, you're using the wrong language. Also look into ATS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The CERT C "de facto" standard is fairly well-known and addresses these issues at some extent:

[SEI CERT C Coding Standard](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/SEI+CERT+C+Coding+Standard)

There should be several static analyzers on the market that supports CERT C.

Answer (score 3):

Same answer [Secure Programming Cookbook for C and C++: Recipes for Cryptography, Authentication, Input Validation & More](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003944)

From the description:

Readers will learn:

- How to avoid common programming
  errors, such as buffer overflows,
  race conditions, and format string
  problems
- How to properly SSL-enable
  applications
- How to create secure channels for
  client-server communication without
  SSL
- How to integrate Public Key
  Infrastructure (PKI) into
  applications Best practices for using
  cryptography properly Techniques and
  strategies for properly validating
  input to programs
- How to launch
  programs securely
- How to use file
  access mechanisms properly
- Techniques
  for protecting applications from
  reverse engineering

Comment: Sounds like a book by somebody misusing the word "security" to mean "privacy/encryption".

Comment: "How to launch programs securely" rofl. proof that modern OS are garbage, you can't do anything without it being a security issue

Comment: "Techniques for protecting applications from reverse engineering" This will just make your program insecure, especially when it's in C....... common sense people?